# Flat or nested data model in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Let me ask my question in a very simpler way.
This:

```
{
    "name": {
        "first": "Joe",
        "last": "Coconut"
    }
}
```

OR this:

```
{
    "first_name": "Joe",
    "last_name": "Coconut"
}
```

But in a very basic form. What if I can either have 5 nested object vs 2 nested with more columns?!

**-- Original --**
I understand modelling of data in mongoDB is relative to application use but as a general rule which model is better?

```
{
    "company": "Amc",
    "clients": [
        {
            "name": "10Gen",
            "contact": "01002033",
            "contracts": {
                "id": 123,
                "price": 1200
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Sun",
            "contact": "677689",
            "contracts": {
                "id": 23,
                "price": 34000
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

vs

```
{
    "company": "Amc",
    "10Gen": {
        "123": 1200,
        "contact": "01002033"
    },
    "Sun": {
        "23": 34000,
        "contact": "677689"
    }
}
```

Since application layer takes care of most operations isn't the second approach more appropriate?

To structure data better is it bad practice to nest data? Say 5 nested documents?

Am I missing a very obvious fact?

Comment: The only difference is, approach 1 is good for supporting indexes. If you don't need to query mongodb based on 'clients.name', 'clients.contact' etc, then you should go for Approach 2, which is space efficient.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I complicated my question a tad. I just simplified what I meant. But I hope the answer would apply for a more complex example as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just FYI:

Consider a very big document. Consider below example ( I have put small no of keys for the documents). And consider the following two update.

```
db.mytest.update({b_e : 1}, {$set : { b_e : 2}})
db.mytest.update({'b.e' : 1}, {$set : { 'b.e' : 2}})
```

In MongoDB updating in second case, will be relatively easy because less no key iteration is required. The cpu activity will be relatively less in second update. This issue you will note when the document contains huge no of keys. In your case, it won't matter because document is very small.

```
Mongo > db.mytest.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5188aae4eadc531d7386f524"),
    "a_b" : 1,
    "a_c" : 1,
    "b_c" : 1,
    "b_d" : 1,
    "b_e" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5188ab14eadc531d7386f525"),
    "a" : {
        "b" : 1,
        "c" : 1
    },
    "b" : {
        "c" : 1,
        "d" : 1,
        "e" : 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so for the name case I prefer and recommend the first form with the nesting.

in addition for the second more involved exmaple, the first version with the array i prefer.  in that scenario several queries are possible which would not be otherwise.  consider the query "find me all documents where there exists a client with contact "677689".  the first form that is easy:

db.collection_name.find( { "clients.contact" : "677689" } )

you could even index on that if this were a hot query :

db.collection_name.ensureIndex( { "clients.contact" : 1 } )

(code above in mongo shell script syntax; can do the same thing in any language with the right syntax thereof of course)